# Eclipse GMF Model selected Wizward could not be started

Tags: eclipse-gmf

In Eclipse GMF I have defined my .ecore .genmodel .gmfgraph .gmfmap .gmftool .gmfgen models and I have generated the model, editor and diagram code.

When I run it as an eclipse application, I can create a standard model, I can also see the generated diagram type, but when I start it (create a diagram) then comes this error message:

```
The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in SmartAdaPro.diagram was unable to load class smartadapro.SmartAdaPro.diagram.part.SmartAdaProCreationWizard. smartadapro.SmartAdaPro.diagram.part.SmartAdaProCreationWizard
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting all generated code, the plugin.xml and MANIFEST.MF, the .genmodel and the .gmfgen model and regenerated in this sequence:

1. .genmodel
2. Model and Edit Code
3. .gmfgen
4. Diagram Code

Then it worked.